# What is best approach to add back button for first view controller in navigation controller?

Tags: ios7

I'm beginner iOS developer, so don't know how to solve my problem correctly. I have one navigation controller and want to make modal transition to another navigation controller that will have back button on it's first view controller.

In my **first navigation controller** I made this:

```
InfoViewController *destinatinViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:destinatinViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**InfoViewController** is UINavigationViewController.

Then I made this in InfoViewController (**second navigation controller**):

```
InfoRootViewController *rootViewController = [[InfoRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoRootViewController" bundle:nil];
[self pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
```

For now I know how to add button to go back, but it has not styling (certainly arrow). As I understand because it is only one view in stack of **second navigation controller**.

So, I need your help to add styled back button for first view controller of navigation controller, because I don't want to make own styling (I'm lazy).

Thanks, for any advance!

**PS:** I made modal transition because, it has animations like from bottom or top. I tried to use custom animations for **pushViewController**, but in iOS 7 they're working not correctly.

Comment: If you're using a modal view controller, then you would typically have a Done or Cancel button. If Done/Cancel don't fit your workflow, then you're not really using the modal behavior properly. You should investigate and fix the original issue (incorrect animations) rather than try to mold modal view controllers to fit your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let someone else help you with the back button issue because I think it's a mistake to create one for a modal view controller that's presented from the bottom of the screen. Typically, such a modal view controller is dismissed with a cancel button or its equivalent. If you really think that you need a back button then you should probably push the view controller onto the existing navigation stack instead of presenting it modally.

However, I am happy to show you how to properly alloc/init a navigation controller and then present it.

I don't know why you're subclassing UINavigationController, but I'm going to pretend that you don't need to (which is probably the case).

```
InfoRootViewController *rootViewController = [[InfoRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoRootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```